# Syntax for List<Student>.class in Android

Tags: java, android, json, objectmapper

What is the syntax for `List<Student>.class` in Java android? This is for getting the type of list of students. Am getting a json string with List of students and that to be parsed to the concrete class.

`objectMapper.readValue(response, List<Student>.class);`

Comment: It's related to json

Answer (score 0):

From java point of view , `.class` file is generated when a `.java` file is compiled. `List.java` is part of core `java.lang package`.

The parameters we give inside the < and > like in your case `Student` is,  dynamic.

There is no way `List.class` (compiled and `.class` generated before you created your `Student` class) know anything about `Student`.

List uses generics for this, the type is provided later, hence .class is independent of the type.